# Bounds for the Expectation of a Greedy Random Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to understand the following process:

1. There are $n$ intervals, each initially of unit length.
2. Select the longest interval, say $I$ with length $|I|$, and set its new length to $p|I|$ where $p \in [0, 1]$ is a freshly drawn uniformly random real number. Alternatively, we can think of setting $I = [0, i]$ where $i \sim U(0,|I|)$ and at the start of this step $I = [0, |I|]$.
3. Go to step 2.

What is known about the behavior of the total remaining (or discarded) length of intervals when iterating this process $cn$ times? For example, when $c = 1$, one may easily see that we expect the total remaining (or discarded) length to be $n/2$. Things seem to get hairy for larger values of $c$.

The best upper bound I can get is $(1/2)^cn$ remaining length in expectation (for integer values $c$), and this comes from ignoring the greediness and just iterating over the intervals in a fixed order.

Comment: It may be useful to construct a sequence, ignoring greediness and using a fixed order, where each term is indexed by c and represents the total length after c iterations on each interval. You would expect this sequence to approach 0 as c approaches infinity. However, a potential problem I see is that this sequence is countable but p is chosen from an uncountable set, so could the limit of this sequence even be defined? I'm not sure. It's certainly a very interesting problem.